# MySQL Search and Replace (Similar Text - Not Exact)

Tags: php, sql, replace

I want to replace this:

```
~ <a href="xxxx">Download</a>
```

with:

```
<div class="down"> ~ <a href="xxxx">Download</a> </div>
```

There are around 300-350 places the `DOWNLOAD` word is repeated. `xxx` is not constant, it changes every time, and the hyper link will be changed every time...

Is it possible to do that with any SQL Query? If it's not possible in SQL, can this be done in php?

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
UPDATE MyTable 
SET MyField = REPLACE(MyField, 
                      '~ <a href="xxxx">Download</a>', 
                      '<div class="down"> ~ <a href="xxxx">Download</a> </div>')
```

Ok, how about rplacing everything around the `"xxxx"`:

```
UPDATE MyTable 
SET MyField = 
REPLACE(
  REPLACE(MyField, 
          '~ <a href=', 
          '<div class="down"> ~ <a href'),  
  '</a>', 
  '</a> </div>')
```

Comment: I think this answer misses a key idea OP expressed, that `"xxxx"` is not a constant, this will differ on each row. At least, that's the meaning I took from OP phrase: "the hyper link will be changed every time".

Comment: @linger,  yes xss is not constant.. it will be changed every time :(

Answer (score 1):

What about a PHP method using [`str_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php)

```
<?php

$string = '~ <a href="xxxx">Download</a>';

$string = str_replace('~ <a href="xxxx">Download</a>', '<div class="down"> ~ <a href="xxxx">Download</a> </div>', $string);

echo $string;
```

Echo's the following in HTML source as:

```
<div class="down"> ~ <a href="xxxx">Download</a> </div>
```

---

Additionally:

```
$link = "page.php";

$string = '~ <a href="xxxx">Download</a>';

$string = str_replace('~ <a href="xxxx">Download</a>', '<div class="down"> ~ <a href="'.$link.'">Download</a></div>', $string);

echo $string;
```

HTML source:

```
<div class="down"> ~ <a href="page.php">Download</a></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Get the rows from table and use something like following.

```
foreach($result as $row)
{
   echo '<div class-="down"><a href = "'. $row['xxxx'] .'" >Download</a></div>';
}
```

Comment: please share more information on  href value. from where it comes.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL has a REGEXP operator, but that works only for "matching", not for doing replacements.

An expression like this:

```
REPLACE(
  REPLACE(col, 
    , '~ <a href="'
    , '<div class="down"> ~ <a href="'
  )
  , '">Download</a>'
  , ">Download</a> </div>'
)
```

might achieve the results you are after **but** the two replacements will be done independently. That is, **all** instances of **`'~ <a href="'`** within the string, not just those instances that are followed by **`Download`**.

I strongly suspect that this won't really work for you, because I suspect that the column you need to perform this operation on contains other instances of these same strings, which do not need to be replaced.

---